# Show prename and lastname as select option in CakePHP

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, select

I want to show a form with CakePHP where users can select an employee. Cake shows the inputfield as "select" which is good. Unfortunately the select input field only shows the `id` of the employee rather than the `prename` and `lastname`.

**Model:**

Reminder:

```
worker_id (reference to Worker model)
```

Worker:

```
id
prename
lastname
```

Here is the PHP part:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Reminder', 
    array('action' => 'add',
        'inputDefaults' => array(
            'label' => false,
            'div' => false
        )
    )
); 

echo $this->Form->input('worker_id', array('empty' => 'Choose an employee'));
echo $this->Form->button('Save', array('type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-green'));
```

I did not find a way to show the `prename` and `lastname` of class `Worker` but keep the `id` as option value in the select field.

How can this be done?

Comment: i didn't get your requirement. Please explain with an example.

Comment: I think you are asking for option attribute, $this->Form->input('worker_id', array('empty' => 'Choose an employee','options'=>$your_listing));

Comment: Hi Nilesh, I added some more explaination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have need to create $your_listing as below

```html
$your_listing = array('2'=>'John Fleming','3'=>'Justin Bond');
```

and used this array in your form helper as below

```html
echo $this->Form->input('worker_id', array('empty' => 'Choose an employee','options'=>$your_listing));
```

So in above example, select box become

```html
<select name="worker_id">
  <option id="">Choose an employee</option>
  <option id="2">John Fleming</option>
  <option id="3">Justin Bond</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Nilesh, what is the best way to get the `$your_listing` array directly from the controller? If you can provide this information, I will approve it as answer! Thanks buddy.

Comment: $your_listing = $this->Article->find('list', array(
        'conditions' => array('Article.status' => 'pending'),'fields'=>array('id','fullname')
    ));

Comment: You have also need to add this is in model... public $virtualFields = array(
    'fullname' => 'CONCAT(User.first_name, " ", User.last_name)'
);

Comment: @NileshDharmik Snippets are for runnuable JS/HTML/CSS stuff, for anything else please use normal code blocks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array to specify the options of the select input.

```
$options =  array(
    'Value 1' => 'Label 1',
    'Value 2' => 'Label 2'
)
echo $this->Form->input('worker_id', $options,  array('empty' => 'Choose an employee'));
```

In you case your labels should be `Worker.id => Worker.prename + Worker.lastname`